# My Register API does not work when testing through postman: "Status Code: 400; Bad Request"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, postman

When Testing, I have attempted to match the input from my `RegisterViewModel`, no matter what different input I have tried using in postman to post the user it does not work, unsure if its something to do with the method or my input in *postman*.

The `RegisterViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string ReEnterPassword { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Heres my attempted input into *postman*:

```
{
 "username" : "user01",
 "password" : "test123",
 "reEnterPassword" : "test123",
 "email" : "user01@example.com",
 "firstName" : "Joe",
 "lastName" : "Bloggs"
}
```

The method being used:

```
[HttpPost("api/auth/register")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> NotWrkingRegister([FromBody] RegisterViewModel user)
{

        if (user.Password != user.ReEnterPassword)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Password don't match");
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {

            var newUser = Mapper.Map<RegisterViewModel, AppUser>(user);

            newUser.UserName = user.Username;

            newUser.APIKey = Guid.NewGuid();
            //newUser.Email = user.Email;

            var userCreationResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.Password);
            if (!userCreationResult.Succeeded)
            {
                foreach (var error in userCreationResult.Errors)
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                return View(user);
            }
            else
            {

                string confirmationToken = userManager.
                       GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser).Result;

                string confirmationLink = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail",
                  "Account", new
                  {
                      userid = newUser.Id,
                      token = confirmationToken
                  },
                   protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("confirmEmail", "api/auth",
                                   new { userId = newUser.Id.ToString(), code = confirmationToken },
                                   protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                callbackUrl = $"http://localhost:49181/api/auth/confirmemail?userId=" + newUser.Id.ToString() + $"&token={confirmationToken}";


                 SendEmail(callbackUrl, newUser);



            }

            UserViewModel _userVM =
                  Mapper.Map<AppUser, UserViewModel>(newUser);
            return new OkObjectResult(_userVM);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Exception thrown while creating JWT: {ex}");
        }
        return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the anti forgery token?

Comment: services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

not sure, I have tried commenting it out in attempts to get different output, when the method is called it doesn't seem to even hit the try catch block.

Comment: Your PostMan request is not passing the anti-forgery token. And `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` means that your code needs it. Hence the 400.

Comment: Getting an Internal server error after commenting out the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] not sure what to do next

Comment: Can you talk us through your level of expertise in C# and MVC / Web API?

Comment: Beginner at best just started working on this project been 4 weeks now. This is my first exposure to all the above technologies.

Comment: The short answer is a) Stop using PostMan b) Put breakpoints in `NotWrkingRegister` and step through it until it fails (to find your bug).

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now, there were duplicated values already registered within the database. After commenting out the`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and running through the code break pointing each individual component, found the problem and rectified and got desired output.